# Choose command order in a function based on an error [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling, tidyverse, purrr

I have three files in a folder with the following names:

```
./multiqc_data$ ls
```

```
file1.json
file2.json
file3.json
```

When I open the files with the [TidyMultiqc package](https://github.com/multimeric/TidyMultiqc) existing NA values in the files might lead to the following error:

```
files <- dir(path,pattern = "*.json")        #locate files
files %>% 
  map(~ load_multiqc(file.path(path, .)))    #parse them

## the error
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                  "mapped_failed_pct": NaN,                 "paired in
                     (right here) ------^
```

I want to create a function to handle this error.

I want every time this error pops up to be able to apply this sed function in all files of the folder.

```
system(paste("gsed -i 's/NaN/null/g'",paste0(path,"*.json")))
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this wrapper :

```
safe_load_multiqc <- function(path, file) {
  tryCatch(load_multiqc(file.path(path, file)), error = function(e) {
    system(paste("gsed -i 's/NaN/null/g'",paste0(path,"*.json")))
    # retry
    load_multiqc(path, file)
  })
}
```

Comment: Wow! I am gonna try it asap

Answer (score 1):

A good way to handle errors in work pipelines like that is using restarts and `withCallingHandlers` and `withRestarts`.

You establish the condition handlers and the recovery protocols (restarts) then you can choose what protocols to use and in which order. Calling handlers allows a much finer control on error conditions than common try-catch.

In the example, I wrote two handlers: removeNaNs (works at folder level) and skipFile (works at file level), if the first fails, the second is executed (simply skipping the file). Of course is an example

I think in your case you can simply run `sed` in every case, nevertheless, I hope this answer meet your looking for a canonical way

Inspiration and Extra lecture: [Beyond Exception Handling: Conditions and Restarts](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html)

```
path <- "../your_path"

# function that does the error_prone task
do_task <- function(path){
  files <- dir(path,pattern = "*.json")        #locate files
  files %>% 
    map(~ withRestart(                         # set an alternative restart
      load_multiqc(file.path(path, .)),        # parsing
      skipFile = function() {                  # if fails, skip only this file      
        message(paste("skipping ", file.path(path, .)))
        return(NULL)
      }))   
}

# error handler that invokes "removeNaN"
removeNaNHandler <- function(e)  tryInvokeRestart("removeNaN")
# error handler that invokes "skipFile"
skipFileHandler <- function(e) tryInvokeRestart("skipFile")

# run the task with handlers in case of error
withCallingHandlers(
  condition = removeNaNHandler,    # call handler (on generic error)
  # condition = skipFileHandler,     # if previous fails skips file
  {
    # run with recovery protocols (can define more than one)
    withRestarts({
      do_task(path)},   
      removeNaN = function()   # protocol "removeNaN"  
      {               
        system(paste("gsed -i 's/NaN/null/g'",paste0(path,"*.json")))
        do_task(path)      # try again
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this open github issue](https://github.com/multimeric/TidyMultiqc/issues/9), a potential solution provided by [Peter Diakumis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2169986/peter-diakumis) is to use `RJSONIO::fromJSON()` in place of `jsonlite::read_json()`. You could adapt this solution to your use-case by e.g. creating your own `load_multiqc()` function:

```r
library(RJSONIO)

load_multiqc_bugfix <- function(paths,
                                plots = NULL,
                                find_metadata = function(...) {
                                  list()
                                },
                                plot_parsers = list(),
                                sections = "general") {
  assertthat::assert_that(all(sections %in% c(
    "general", "plot", "raw"
  )), msg = "Only 'general', 'plot' and 'raw' (and combinations of those) are valid items for the sections parameter")

  # Vectorised over paths
  paths %>%
    purrr::map_dfr(function(path) {
      parsed <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(path)

      # The main data is plots/general/raw
      main_data <- sections %>%
        purrr::map(~ switch(.,
          general = parse_general(parsed),
          raw = parse_raw(parsed),
          plot = parse_plots(parsed, plots = plots, plot_parsers = plot_parsers)
        )) %>%
        purrr::reduce(~ purrr::list_merge(.x, !!!.y), .init = list()) %>%
        purrr::imap(~ purrr::list_merge(.x, metadata.sample_id = .y))

      # Metadata is defined by a user function
      metadata <- parse_metadata(parsed = parsed, samples = names(main_data), find_metadata = find_metadata)
      purrr::list_merge(metadata, !!!main_data) %>%
        dplyr::bind_rows()
    }) %>%
    # Only arrange the columns if we have at least 1 column
    `if`(
      # Move the columns into the order: metadata, general, plot, raw
      ncol(.) > 0,
      (.) %>%
        dplyr::relocate(dplyr::starts_with("raw")) %>%
        dplyr::relocate(dplyr::starts_with("plot")) %>%
        dplyr::relocate(dplyr::starts_with("general")) %>%
        dplyr::relocate(dplyr::starts_with("metadata")) %>%
        # Always put the sample ID at the start
        dplyr::relocate(metadata.sample_id),
      .
    )
}
```